# How to invoke custom Javascript in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm loading third party webpage that contains following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onDomReady(function() { some_code1; });
</script>
```

into WebBrowser component. After `some_code1` had executed I need to do some manipulations with Dom that will make `some_code1` invalid. The question is how to determine that `some_code1` had executed?

I cant't do

```
private void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DoRequiredManipulations();
}
```

Since this event will occur *before* `some_code1` has executed and will make it invalid.

Also I can't do

```
private void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    web.Document.InvokeScript("doSome_code1");
    DoRequiredManipulations();
}
```

Since `some_code1` is declared as an anonymous function.

It seems that the only way to do it is this:

```
private void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var script = GetScriptText(web.DocumentText);
    //execute script in webbrowser
    DoRequiredManipulations();
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to execute this script in webbrowser. I had tried `web.Navigate("javascript: " + script);` but it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do that:

```
HtmlElement scriptEl = web.Document.CreateElement("script");
(scriptEl.DomElement as IHTMLScriptElement).text = "function myscript() { " + script.Text + " }";
web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0].AppendChild(scriptEl);
web.Document.InvokeScript("myscript");
```