# C# WebBrowser Visual Studio 2010 IsScriptEnabled not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to execute a javascript function in a WebBroswer control in C#. However when I try to set the IsScriptEnabled property, I get an error saying that there is no definition for IsScriptEnabled. All of the tutorials and examples I have seen involve using the InvokeScript function but I cannot seem to use it with my C# WebBroswer, using VisualStudio 2010, .NET Framework 4.5.1. Any thoughts?

For example...I have a WebBrowser form in my .NET application and am attempting to use the IsScriptEnabled property...

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = "True";
        }
    }
}
```

The error reported is as follows...

```
1   'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'IsScriptEnabled' and no extension method 'IsScriptEnabled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\matthew alt\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\wpfapplication1\wpfapplication1\mainwindow.xaml.cs   26  25  WpfApplication1
```

Referencing this post...

[C# Invoke JavaScript in WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694767/c-sharp-invoke-javascript-in-webbrowser)

Comment: Please post code, thank you !

Comment: That property doesn't exist. Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739583/how-to-invoke-custom-javascript-in-system-windows-forms-webbrowser

Comment: So, does that allow me to execute pre-existing javascript code on a webpage within the WebBrowser element?

Comment: @Bubo the post you referenced, discuss about `WebBrowser` control for windows phone not WPF : `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser`

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like javascript is not supported in this WebBrowser control to the extent that the website would like. When I attempt to perform the action manually it does not perform properly...looks like I was using the wrong tool for the job!

Answer (score 0):

har07's comment had the correct answer: the mobile `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser` has a property `IsScriptEnabled`, while desktop `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` doesn't.

The latter `WebBrowser` supports JavaScript, but scripts might be disabled by the your Internet Explorer settings.